# How do I calculate the modulus of elasticity of a spring when I don't know the cross-sectional area?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, elasticity

'An elastic spring of natural length 1.5 m has one end attached to a fixed point.
A horizontal force of magnitude 4 N is applied to the other end and compresses the spring to a length of 1 m.
Find the modulus of elasticity of the spring.' is a problem I've been asked to solve, and I've never seen a problem of this style before. I'm aware the modulus = stress/strain, but I don't know how to find stress without knowing the cross-sectional area.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are overthinking the question. Go back to before you knew about stress and strain...

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: What is the $k$ of the spring?

Comment: k = F/e = 4/0.5 = 8, right?

Comment: The spring was compressed by 1m

Comment: No, it was compressed to 1m, and 1.5m - 1m = 0.5m

Comment: Cool - trying to do too many things.

Comment: Do you know the answer to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The modulus of a spring is defined as $$\frac{\text{tension in spring}}{\text{fractional change in spring's length}}$$
The fractional change in the spring's length means
$$\frac{\text{extension}}{\text{original length}}$$
The modulus of a spring is defined differently from the Young modulus (or indeed any elastic modulus) of a solid. This has to be the case, because a spring is a particular *thing* whereas a solid is a *material* whose extent is not defined.

It is true that the fractional change in a spring's length could be called the *strain* in the spring. But we don't divide the tension in the spring by the spring's cross-sectional area. This is because doing so wouldn't yield a quantity that affects the spring in the same way that stress affects a material. [For example, if two helical springs are made of the same wire wound into different diameter helices, and both are put under the same tension, tension/area is smaller for the fatter spring, but the fatter spring stretches more than the thinner (in other words the strain is greater.)]

*Spring modulus* comes into its own if you imagine that a manufacturer has coiled steel wire into a helix that is many metres long, and will cut this helix into pieces that (s)he will sell as 'springs'. All of these will have the same spring modulus, whatever their length, whereas their spring constants (tension/extension) will depend on their lengths.

Comment: So the answer is λ = T/change = T/(x/L) = 4/(0.5/1.5) = 12 ?

Comment: And the units would be N, right? Tension (N) divided by extension/length (m/m cancels, so unitless)?

Comment: Far be it from me to supply an answer to a homework-type question, but I think you've understood.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but if I'm not incorrect modulus of elasticity = stress/strain. stress has units of pressure (Pa), and strain is unitless. Is this not a contradiction with what we've said?

Comment: No, because the modulus of a spring is defined differently from an elastic modulus of a solid material !

Comment: In what way is it different?

Comment: I've given the definition of the modulus of the spring in my answer. And you seemed to know that the elastic modulus of a solid is defined as stress/strain – which is not the same.

Comment: Yes, I understand your definition, but I'm confused as to why there are two definitions both for modulus of elasticity.

Comment: The word 'modulus' is being used somewhat differently in the two contexts. But we can probably live with this.

Comment: I see. Not sure I fully understand, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: Try this analogy. The area of a rectangle is defined as length x breadth. Yet we talk about the area under a velocity-time graph equalling displacement (measured in m)

Comment: @Beezo  I've added a bit to the middle of my answer. Hope it helps.